# How to get Active Directory to Prohibit User Installations using Group policy

Tags: group-policy

I have installed Windows Server 2019, Active Directory, and Windows 11 clients. I have created an Organizational Unit (OU). I then applied Group Policy in OU. Some of the restriction are working but others are not.

Some of the Group Policies are not  displaying in the OU.

"Prohibit User Install"  User Configuration>Policies>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Windows Installer. is not showing "Prohibit User Install"

User Configuration>Policies>Administrative Templates>System>Power Management  is not showing   power management policies

How to show these group policy settings which are not displaying?

[image: power management]

Comment: Tell us how "Prevent user install" is not working.

Comment: @GregAskew its not showing no option of "Prevent user install"  there ar other oprion but  "prevent user install" is not available  here -> Configuration>Policies>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Windows Installer.

Comment: Tell us what "it's" is. GPMC?